# How can I copy value from ostringstream to string?

Tags: c++

I tried :

```
ostringstream oss;
read a string from file and put to oss;
string str;
str << oss.str();// error here "error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in 'oss >> str' "
```

If I use `str = oss.str();`
Instead of printing the value of the string, it prints out `"....0xbfad75c40xbfad75c40xbf...."` likes memory address.
Can anybody tell me why?
Thank you.

Comment: Add the code that reads from the file into oss.

Answer (score 24):

```
string str = oss.str(); // this should do the trick
```

Comment: @user: Perhaps you put garbage *in*?

Comment: garbage in? what do you mean?

Comment: @user: You are getting garbage *out* of your stringstream.  Perhaps the reason is that you are putting garbage *into* it, with the code that's represented by "*read a string from file and put to oss*"...

Comment: ifstream ifs("file");    oss << ifs;

Comment: @user552279: well that's your problem. That's not the proper way to read from a file. Also, Why are you trying to read from a file into a stream? Odds are you can read from the file directly (it's a stream too!).

Comment: ah because the string has some special characters (+ - ...) thus i want to put the string to ostringstream thus i can strip it easily

Comment: @user does the file contains non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to copy the whole file to a stringstream, then this:

```
oss << ifs;
```

is wrong.  All that does is prints the address of ifs.  What you want to do is this:

```
oss << ifs.rdbuf();
```

And then of course, to copy that to a string, like the others are saying:

```
str = oss.str();
```

If you just want to get a single line, then skip the stringstream, and just use getline:

```
std::getline(ifs,str);
```

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is an operator defined on streams, which a `string` is not.  You just want to use `=` here.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make any sense.  `oss.str()` returns a `std::string`.  You can't stream a `string` into a `string`.  You either need `str = oss.str()`, or use a standard `stringstream` instead, and do `ss >> str`.

Answer (score 0):

the operator "<<" is usable for ostringstream and you are using it for a string.
for string I think you can use append function:

str.append(oss.str());